# Docker cp does not copy into existing directory, instead always creates subdirectory

Tags: docker

I have a helper shell script to copy a large amount of files (project source code) into an apache container (specifically the `var/www/html` directory. (I'm not using host volumes for the entire project because it's an obscenely large amount (Magento 2) of space).

The problem is, `docker cp` always creates a subdirectory rather than copying the files into the directory.

Pertinent part of the script looks like this:

```sh
SOURCE_DIR=/c/projects/foo/bar # actually pulled from .env file but this is what it comes out to
docker cp $SOURCE_DIR/. $(docker-compose ps -q apache_container|awk '{print $1}'):/var/www/html/
```

According to the Docker Documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/, the logic should be:

- `SRC_PATH specifies a directory` - check: `/c/projects/foo/bar` is a directory

  - `DEST_PATH exists and is a directory` check: `/var/www/html/` is a directory in the container

    - `SRC_PATH does end with /. (that is: slash followed by dot)` check: `$SOURCE_DIR/.` = `/c/projects/foo/bar/.`

      - "the *content* of the source directory is copied into this directory" - nope, doesn't happen.

Expected behavior: contents of foo/bar directory are copied **into** `var/www/html` in the container.

Actual behavior: directory `bar` created in `var/www/html`, so I end up having `var/www/html/bar` with its contents.

This is using Docker Desktop on Windows 10 (not running in WSL).

I've also tried various combinations like `docker cp $SOURCE_DIR/.*`, removing the slashes and dot, hardcoding the path of the string in rather than using a variable, removing the trailing slash from `/var/www/html/`, using a relative path with a test directory, etc. It ALWAYS copies the host directory into the container directory, never just the host directory contents.

Comment: Can you do this using a Dockerfile and a `COPY` step instead?  (Anything you `docker cp` in will get lost as soon as the container exits, and you can use `docker build` instead of writing your own script to replicate it.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I would but that requires adding the src directory of the project to the build context, doesn't it? I had it like that originally but build times were incredibly slow. I'm doing this with a `docker-compose` setup so I have the `var/www/html` as a named volume, so it persists even after container exit.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since you posted this but I just hit this same problem and it seems to be something to do with how docker cp doesn't play well with certain characters in a folder name. In my case it was a hyphen that I wasn't able to change and I knew would always be part of the folder name.

Found a case where this had been reported for colons in docker cp and the solution was to escape with a backslash  https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/1125

I tried this with something like the following:

```
targetFolder=${targetFolder//-/\\-}
```

But unlike the github issue above, mine was the target folder not the source filename and it just created a new folder with a backslash in it

The only solution that did work for me was to copy the files to a temporary place with a safe folder name and then docker exec a mv command afterwards as so:

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER /bin/bash -c "mv ${tempFolder}/* ${targetFolder}"
```